# One rewrite rule not working out of the 3 in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following content in the htaccess file. The first and second block of redirect rules are working but the third is not. Any clues on what can be going wrong?

```
#   Mod_security can interfere with uploading of content such as attachments. If you
#   cannot attach files, remove the "#" from the lines below.
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#   SecFilterEngine Off
#   SecFilterScanPOST Off
#</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 500 default

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule [^/]+/.+-([\d]+)/p([\d]+)/ showthread.php?t=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule [^/]+/.+-([\d]+)/ showthread.php?t=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond ${ErrorMap:$1|Unknown} !Unknown
rewriterule ^(.*\.(html)) ${ErrorMap:$1|404} [R=301]

    #   If you are having problems with the rewrite rules, remove the "#" from the
    #   line that begins "RewriteBase" below. You will also have to change the path
    #   of the rewrite to reflect the path to your XenForo installation.
    #RewriteBase /xenforo

    #   This line may be needed to enable WebDAV editing with PHP as a CGI.
    #RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is the part which is not working. I am trying to redirect all non www links to www links.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would apply the non-www -> www rewriteRules first. In the order you are presenting them, if the `showthread.php` rule matches, and rewrites, then the `[L]` or 'last rule' flag, will prevent any further rewriting.

Try them in this order:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond ${ErrorMap:$1|Unknown} !Unknown
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(html)) ${ErrorMap:$1|404} [R=301]

RewriteRule [^/]+/.+-([\d]+)/p([\d]+)/ showthread.php?t=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule [^/]+/.+-([\d]+)/ showthread.php?t=$1 [NC,L]
```

You could also try the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) non-www -> www rule, it's solid!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=127.0.0.1
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: No luck even with the changed order.